# Micro USB phone into USB-C integrated slot in a car

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have a USB-C female port in my car and my smartphone only has a micro USB connector. Is there any risk to plug my phone in with a micro USB/USB-C adapter?

I know that USB-C can deliver up to 100 W of power and I'm not sure if the integrated USB-C device in my car will be "smart" enough to limit the power delivered. I cannot find any information in the car manual neither find a definitive answer on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be safe to use a type-C to micro type-B adapter.

The 100W power delivery that USB-C provides can only be used by another USB-C device. That's because there are extra pins that communicate the power requirements and allow both devices to agree on a power mode.

If those pins aren't connected (like when converting to USB 2.0 or 3.0 Type A/B), then the USB-C port will deliver the standard 5V power over the power pins to remain backwards compatible. There will be no harm to the phone.

This backwards compatibility might provide only 900 mA of current as that's what USB 3.0 specifies. It might be a slower charge than those 12V car outlet chargers can do.